# sphinx about has misspelled word

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-595/sphinx

> I'm a bot, constantly **posing** puzzles in my Lair.

posing => posting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "pose" a question or a puzzle means to state it, expecting other people to consider the answer.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pose

> 5. to assert, state, or put forward

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pose

> 1a : to set forth or offer for attention or consideration

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pose

> 1.1 : Raise (a question or matter for consideration)

This is not a typo: it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).